# QNetworkAccessManager times out with a large file post

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm having an issue with QNetworkAccessManager (specifically from PyQt, so please mind the Python code)

I am trying to use it to POST a file, but I get a `QNetworkReply::TimeoutError` after ~60 seconds

```
self._manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
self._manager.finished.connect(self._onFinished)
... set up the request (code omitted) ...
self._post_reply = self._manager.post(self._post_request, postData)
self._post_reply.uploadProgress.connect(self._onUploadProgress)
```

And the finished handler:

```
def _onFinished(self, reply):
    if reply.error() == QNetworkReply.TimeoutError:
        # I get here after ~60 seconds of uploading
```

And the uploadProgress handler:

```
def _onUploadProgress(self, bytes_sent, bytes_total):
    ... code to update UI progress bar (code omitted) ...
    # This does get called repeatedly for the entire duration before getting a timeout error
```

Is there some way to handle this? Or somehow change the timeout duration?

Comment: read this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/30031/qnetworkreply-network-reply-timeout-helper

Comment: @eyllanesc thanks for the link. Judging by the code, I think that could only be used to shorten the timeout (close the connection early) but not lengthen it. Qt's internal timeout isn't being overridden.